# Xcode 11.6 fails with: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter application using Firebase / Firestore. In my flutter application flutter build iOS is working but in Xcode the Archive and building in General fails with

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I already tried:

- keychain access -> right click on login -> lock & unlock again -> clear Xcode project and make build again.
- also pod deintegrate etc. is not working

But it is not working. Also tried setting up new project but after firestore integration it fails.

```
The domain/default pair of (/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bhnxzkbbayxxhjauqwbcxaiedcis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/ios/Flutter/App.framework/Info.plist, CFBundleExecutable) does not exist
fatal error: lipo: can't map input file: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bhnxzkbbayxxhjauqwbcxaiedcis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/ios/Flutter/App.framework/ (Invalid argument)
fatal error: lipo: can't map input file: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bhnxzkbbayxxhjauqwbcxaiedcis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/ios/Flutter/App.framework/ (Invalid argument)
Failed to extract x86_64 for /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bhnxzkbbayxxhjauqwbcxaiedcis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/ios/Flutter/App.framework/. Running lipo -info:
fatal error: lipo: can't map input file: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bhnxzkbbayxxhjauqwbcxaiedcis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/ios/Flutter/App.framework/ (Invalid argument)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: could you solve it?

Comment: @Nehal using a different machine solved it so I guess it was something in the cache of my PC. But it was not in derived data or something there cause I deleted and cleaned everything like 1000 times before trying another solution like using a different pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so in my case the problem occurred after a flutter upgrade. My app is on the stable channel and I updated it to the current stable version.

before that it was running on 1.17.5 there everything was working fine, the error occurred on 1.20.0

so the solution was a downgrade back to 1.17.5

Answer (score 0):

[image]In my case it worked when set Excluded Architectures -> arm64